# Google data highlighter is not picking up changes to my pages

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console, sitemap, analytics

I submitted sitemaps without error to Google Search Console.  I also used the data Highlighter after two of my pages were indexed in Google.

I made slight changes to the HTML content but these changes are not reflected in Google data Highlighter. I can view the changes on my site.

How do I get data highlighter to see the most recent version of the pages with the HTML changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to delete the old page and publish a new page/set, because [Google data highlighter tool does not pickup changes automatically](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2692911?hl=en)

> Each time Google crawls pages on your site, Data Highlighter extracts
>   data and makes the data available for rich snippets. If you make
>   significant changes to the way your pages display information or to
>   the site's URLs, you should delete the original page sets and teach
>   Data Highlighter about the new structure of your site.

If you think your content is changed frequently in your website, then I prefer to use [schema tags for structure data](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data), so next time when you edit the content, then schema tags will be same but the content inside will be changed automatically and that Google will pickup automatically after re-crawl.

Comment: do i want to resubmit the sitemap to google?

Comment: No sitemap is completely different thing.  I think you misunderstood the concept of data highlighter tools. Data highlighter tool extract data which you've highlight while using that tool. That extracted data is not updated automatically when you make any changes. It's just saved somewhere in Google database. You have to unpublish old pages and publish new page/set, so Google extract another data about that pages.

Comment: but in my Data highlighter not reflect change. Ok. you tell about when i delete old Data highlighter from the tool then create a fresh one. but i was tried by creating new one  that time i didn't see nothing to be reflected. ok as of now i will try with delete old one .

Comment: It takes some time. Google extract your new data when they re-crawl your webpages again.